# GetPixel() only returns FFFFFF

Tags: c

Right now I have a window which is completely a blank yellow color. For some reason, when I call GetPixel(), I only get 0xFFFFFFFF (CLR_INVALID). 
Here's my minimalized code:

```
HWND _hwndPP =  FindWindow(NULL, "Test Window");
COLORREF hdcScreen = GetDC(_hwndPP);
printf("%X", GetPixel(hdcScreen, 10, 10));
ReleaseDC(_hwndPP, hdcScreen);
```

EDIT:
Changed COLORREF to HDC, and it didn't change anything.
Yes, I run a 64-bit system. Does that mean I can't use this function? If so, how would I then check the color of specific pixel?

Comment: `hdcScreen` must be of type `HDC`. Also, have you checked the return values (of FindWindow and GetDC)?

Comment: Does it really return 0x00FFFFFF (Pure white) or 0xFFFFFFFF (`CLR_INVALID`)

Comment: `GetDC` returns an `HDC`, not a `COLORREF`. Declare the variable as an `HDC` instead, and pass the proper `HDC` type variable to `GetPixel` instead. When in doubt, check the documentation at MSDN.

Comment: added more information.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume you are using 64-bit Windows.

`GetDC()` returns an `HDC`, which as a pointer, is a 64-bit value. Then, you are converting it to a `COLORREF`, truncating the DC to 32 bits. When you then ask Win32 for the colour of your pixel, it can't because your HDC is missing some bits. `GetPixel()` then returns `CLR_INVALID` or `0xFFFFFFFF` that you interpret as pure white since you were expecting a valid colour.

On a related note, I'm also guessing your non-minimised code contains casts to and from `COLORREF`. As a rule of thumb, you should rarely (if not never) have to cast in Win32 code. If you have to cast, you are probably using the wrong set of functions or the wrong type of arguments.

Comment: Rarely cast? What about the `(HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW+1)` horror? Granted, most casts are hidden behind a nice(?) macro (`MAKEINTRESOURCE`...), but there are so many of them that you are bound to write some casts manually somewhere...

Comment: @rodrigo: It's a rule of thumb. If you cast to use a documented trick or by using a provided macro, then obviously things are fine. If you cast to shut the compiler up, then things start falling apart.